# Getting error when inserting a jsonb to a table using trigger functions

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert, jsonb

I'm currently inserting this data `{"curr": "testcurr","nm": "testnm"}`
to a view.

A trigger function is then run to insert into the original tables instead.

I'm getting an error `column "curr" does not exist` from the trigger function.

Here is the part of my code:

```
IF (tg_op = 'INSERT') THEN
                NEW."dat"= jsonb_build_object("curr",NEW."curr","symb",NEW."symb");
                NEW."ct"=now();
                INSERT INTO data.tbl
                    (
                    "nm",
                    "dat",
                    "ct",
                    )
                    VALUES
                    (
                    NEW."nm",
                    NEW."dat"
                    NEW."ct"
                    )returning "id" into NEW.id;
END
```

As you can see, the original table does not contain the 'curr' column, but my post data shouldn't have any problem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
jsonb_build_object("curr",NEW."curr","symb",NEW."symb")
```

to:

```
jsonb_build_object('curr',NEW."curr",'symb',NEW."symb")
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html
look at the example - to get key `"foo"` you pass string `'foo'`

double quotes are for identifiers - column, relation etc names - check https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: thanks, I got another error now: `cannot insert into column "curr" of view "tblview"`

Comment: apparently you are trying to insert a row into a view, which can't be done by the view origin. that would be the different question and will require different code sample